# Panda dataframe groupby and summation, within group, across row values rather than by columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There seems to be much online examples on the Dataframe groupby() method which seems to describe grouping with-by columns and data across multiple rows (Series) i.e. going "top-to-bottom"

Given 2 dataframes df_1 and df_2:

```
df_1:
                  Instru_1  Instru_2  Instru_3  Instru_5  Instru_6  Instru_7
2020-10-01        10        10        20        20        10        30
```

where row values are classification IDs and

```
df_2:
                   Instru_1  Instru_2  Instru_3  Instru_5  Instru_6  Instru_7
2020-10-01         0.1       0.2       0.2       0.2       0.2       0.1
```

where row values are weights summing to 1.0

Is groupby() still the way forward if I need to group across row (values) of df_1 where number of instruments can be indeterminate, to get a result df_result:

df_result:

```
                  10         20        30
2020-10-01        0.5        0.4       0.1

where: The columns are the classification IDs from df_1 record 
       The values are the sum for each classification ID from df_2
```

(e.g. Classif ID=10, element value = 0.1 + 0.2 + 0.2 = 0.5,  Classif ID=20, element = 0.2 + 0.2 = 0.4 and ID=30, element = 0.1)

```
Is the quickest still to to perform multiple steps (merge df_1 and df_2 and process per row) ?
Step 1: Enum row 1 classification Ids and create df_result
Step 2: Enum row 2 and perform the summation per classification (this looks tricky!)
```

Any advice on best approach would be appreciated.. (or pointers to grouping across row values..) Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

You could try concat with reshaping and groupby:

```
u = pd.concat((df1,df2),keys=['cols','rows'])
out = (u.unstack().T.reset_index(-1)
       .groupby(['level_1','cols'])['rows'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0))
```

---

```
print(out)

             10   20   30
2020-10-01  0.5  0.4  0.1
```

---

Sample Run for multiple cols:

[image]

Comment: does get_dummies work if the second row is completely different from the first row? like will there become 12 columns after get_dummies?

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but I mean if the second row is (40,40,50,50,60,60), then wouldn't get_dummies return 12 columns?

Answer (score 1):

A bit ugly, but here's a way to do it by unstacking the dataframes and joining, followed by a group by, sum and stacking:

```
df3 = df1.unstack().to_frame().join(df2.unstack().to_frame(), lsuffix='l', rsuffix='r')

df4 = df3.reset_index().groupby(['level_1', '0l']).sum('0r').reset_index().pivot_table('0r', 'level_1', '0l')

df4.index.name = None
df4.columns.name = None

print(df4)
             10   20   30
2020-10-01  0.5  0.4  0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try:

```
s1, s2 = df1.stack(), df2.stack()
out = s2.groupby([s2.droplevel(1).index, s2.index.map(s1)]).sum().unstack()
```

**Details:**

`stack` the dataframes `df1` and `df2` thereby creating multiindex series `s1` and `s2`:

```
>>> s1
2020-10-01  Instru_1    10
            Instru_2    10
            Instru_3    20
            Instru_5    20
            Instru_6    10
            Instru_7    30
dtype: int64

>>> s2
2020-10-01  Instru_1    0.1
            Instru_2    0.2
            Instru_3    0.2
            Instru_5    0.2
            Instru_6    0.2
            Instru_7    0.1
dtype: float64
```

`map` the index of `s2` with series `s1` to get the columns for the new dataframe i.e `10, 20, 30...`:

```
>>> s2.index.map(s1)
Int64Index([10, 10, 20, 20, 10, 30], dtype='int64')
```

Finally `group` series `s2` on `level=0` along with the above mapped columns and aggregate using `sum` followed by `unstack` to `reshape`:

```
>>> out
             10   20   30
2020-10-01  0.5  0.4  0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

- prepare data frames by naming row and column indexes
- `unstack()` to change to row based
- `join()` to bring the two unstacked DFs together as rows
- now it's simple `groupby()`
- `unstack()` to change back to column based as required

```
df_1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""                  Instru_1  Instru_2  Instru_3  Instru_5  Instru_6  Instru_7
2020-10-01        10        10        20        20        10        30"""), sep="\s+")

df_2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""                   Instru_1  Instru_2  Instru_3  Instru_5  Instru_6  Instru_7
2020-10-01         0.1       0.2       0.2       0.2       0.2       0.1"""), sep="\s+")

df_1.columns.set_names("instrument", inplace=True)
df_1.index.set_names("date", inplace=True)
df_2.columns.set_names("instrument", inplace=True)
df_2.index.set_names("date", inplace=True)


(df_1.unstack().to_frame().rename(columns={0:"classification"})
 .join(df_2.unstack().to_frame().rename(columns={0:"weight"}))
 .groupby(["date","classification"]).sum()
 .unstack(1).droplevel(0, axis=1)
)
```

| date | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-10-01 | 0.5 | 0.4 | 0.1 |

Comment: Thanks. The clear steps given helps understanding of some of the other solutions and underlying principles - c.f. "teaching someone how to fish" and then maybe after, further research on other "map2 + "crosstab" solution proposal..